# XML Parser em PHP não funciona

Tags: php, xml, xmlhttprequest, simplexml, simplexml-load-string

Estou tentando implementar um código de XML PARSE em PHP, acredito que configurei seguindo a lógica certa, mas não está funcionando.
Funciona se eu usar com um feed RSS, porém o Feed RSS não tem os links das imagens.
A meta final é retirar os seguintes valores:

```
<nome>
<descricao>
<link_produto>
<link_imagem>
<preco_promocao>
<preco_normal>
<parcelas>
<vl_parcelas>
```

Está retornando uma página em branco, no log de erros ele retorna o seguinte:

```
[27-May-2017 04:18:20 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/SITE/public_html/va/artigos-complexos/afilio/afilio-vitrinexml.php on line 12
```

A função:

```
simplexml_load_file
```

funciona perfeitamente por que

```
allow_url_fopen
```

está ativada no php do servidor.

O código é o seguinte:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/va/artigos-complexos/afilio/afilio-vitrine.css" type="text/css" />

<div class="mainproductebayfloatright-bottom">

<?php
/* XML PARSER*/

$feedurl = "http://v2.afilio.com.br/aff/aff_get_boutique.php?boutiqueid=37930-895687&token=53e355b0a09ea0.74300807&progid=1199&format=XML";

$rss = simplexml_load_file($feedurl);

foreach ($rss->boutique->produto as $item) {
    $link = $item->link_do_produto;
    $title = $item->nome;
    $description = $item->descricao;

    ?>

        <div class="aroundebay">
        <div id="aroundebay2">


<?php
        print "<div class=\"titleebay\"><a href=\"$link\">" . $title . "</a></div>";
        print $description;
    ?>
        </div>
        </div>

</div>
<?php  }
```

Código CSS:

```
.mainproductebayfloat-bottom {
    display: block;
}
#aroundebay {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    display: table;
}
#aroundebay2 {
    border: 1px #48719D;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    color: #48719D;
    margin-left: 5px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1px) {
    #aroundebay2 {
        height: 300px;
        width: 95%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    #aroundebay2 {
        height: 220px;
        width: 95%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    #aroundebay2 {
        height: 250px;
        width: 95%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {
    #aroundebay2 {
        height: 220px;
        width: 48%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 720px) {
    #aroundebay2 {
        height: 215px;
        width: 48%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
    #aroundebay2 {
        height: 250px;
        width: 30%;
    }
}
#aroundebay2 a {
    font-weight: bolder;
}
.titleebay {
    background: #48719D;
    padding: 2px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 1px 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 1px 1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 1px 1px;
}
.titleebay a {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: #000 1px 1px 1px;
    height: 38px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
.titleebay a:hover {
    color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

o erro é nessa linha:

```
foreach ($rss->boutique->produto as $item) {
```

pq $rss->boutique->produto é null
O que ocorre é que boutique é o elemento raiz, e portanto já está carregado na variável $rss, pode pular a chamada a ele, tente fazer assim:

```
foreach ($rss->produto as $item) {
```

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado.